# Tensorflow on android: directly build app in python?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

The sample app given by google for tensorflow on android is written in C++.

I have a tensorflow application written in python. This application currently runs on desktop. I want to move the application to android platform. Can I use bazel to build the application that is written in python directly for android? Thanks.

Also sample tensorflow app in python on android will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no simple way to run tensorflow on android. Typically, you would only have to use [inference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) (runtime), not training.

Another way is to use [TensorFlow serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) to host models in the cloud and issue RPC calls from an Android client.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use python in my android application with some 3rd party terminals like **SL4A and Qpython**. Those will support to run the python files directly in our android application so we have to install SL4A apk's and we need to call that intent.But these will support for some level I guess.

I tried to import tensorflow in that terminal it shows module not found. So I thought this tensorflow will not work in these terminals.

So I am trying to create one .pb file from the python files which are working in unix platform.So We need to **include that output .pb file in our android** application and we need to change the c++ code regarding that .pb file.I am thinking in this way.let see it will work or not.I will update soon if it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your tensorflow model on your desktop and save it as a .pb file. Then you can add this model to your android project and make use of it to make predictions on the android device.

Its like training(which involves heavy computations) on a desktop machine(which is more powerful) and using the model to make predictions(which involves less computations) on a mobile device(comparatively less powerful).

This is a link to a great video by Siraj Raval

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFWKdLOxykE